# How to display a list of random tags in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, random, tags

I have used the following code to try and display a list of random tags:

```
<?php wp_tag_cloud('smallest=10&largest=10&number=5&format=list&order=rand&orderby=count'); ?>
```

This does display a list of 5 tags, but the order isn't random, and doesn't change when I reload the page.

Any help of how to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for an answer to this myself tonight and I thought I would post a solution.

My requirements were for random tags displayed each page refresh and the ability to exclude certain tags. For my purposes I put it in functions.php because I hate cluttering up my template files with functions.

**The Function** - insert this in your functions.php file

```
function jr_get_tags_but_exclude() {
    $args = array('exclude' => '36 17'); // see notes below
        $alltags = get_tags( $args );
        shuffle($alltags);
        $count=0;
        if ($alltags) {
            foreach($alltags as $tag) {
                $count++;
                echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">'.$tag->name.'</a>';
        if( $count >19 ) break;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Call** - insert this in your template page

```
<?php jr_get_tags_but_exclude(); ?>
```

**Notes**

- To exclude tags you will need the tag ID . The simplest way to get the ID is to go to posts -> tags and hover over the tag you want to exclude. The ID # will be given in the url bar on the bottom of your browser when hovered on, `&tag_ID=9`, for example.
- The Wordpress codex for `get_tags` says to put only a blank space seperating each tag ID, no commas required.
- Regarding randomizing the results, `rand`is not an available option or `$arg` for `get_tags`, unfortunately.
- To change the number of tags shown adjust `if ( $count >19 )` 19 = 20 tags, 29 = 30, etc.
- `shuffle($alltags);` is what does the randomization
- `$count=0;` starts the counter, `$count++;` counts each tag posted, `if( $count >19 ) break;` ends the loop, in this case after 20 tags are posted.

**Credits and References**

mostly based on these gent's solutions

1. [wordpress random tag issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897186/wordpress-random-tag-issue)
2. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26112/how-to-limit-and-display-tag
3. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-exclude-tag

wordpress codex for get_tags

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags

**In Your Template File** - no function needed

```
<?php
    $args = array('exclude' => '36 17'); // see notes below
        $alltags = get_tags( $args );
        shuffle($alltags);
        $count=0;
        if ($alltags) {
            foreach($alltags as $tag) {
                $count++;
                echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">'.$tag->name.'</a>';
        if( $count >19 ) break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Please reply with any mistakes noticed so I can edit them.